# Kendo UI - Radial Guage - Dial Colors

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Radial Gauge, but I need to change the fill colors of the numbers on the dial.  I do not see anything in the documentation on these specifically.

Does anyone know how to modify these?

```
 @(Html.Kendo().RadialGauge()
                  .Name("gauge")
                  .Pointer(pointer => pointer.Value(65))
                  .Scale(scale => scale
                      .MinorUnit(5)
                      .StartAngle(-30)
                      .EndAngle(210)
                      .Max(180)
                  )
                )

<script>
    function change(e) {
        $("#gauge").data("kendoRadialGauge").value($("#gauge-value").val());
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  @(Html.Kendo().RadialGauge()
                  .Name("gauge3")
                          .Pointer(pointer => pointer.Value(45).Color("#D13A3F"))
                  .Scale(scale => scale
                      .MinorUnit(5)
                      .StartAngle(-30)
                      .EndAngle(210)
                      .Max(180)
                    .Labels(labels => labels
                    .Font("10px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif")
                    .Color("#fff")

            )
                  )
                )
```